# MVVM + Datacontext + DataTemplate + Blend = problems

Tags: mvvm, datatemplate, datacontext, blend

I'm currently using MVVM in a WPF project, all works very well.
I have one Master view and many Detail views that I manage using a currentView property in my MasterViewModel. By using a datatemplate, I bind a view to a viewmodel.
In fact, my master view has a contentcontrol whose content property is binded to my CurrentView property. When I set this currentview property to a viewmodel or another, it calls the corresponding template.

My problem is that using this, my detail views doesn't have explicit datacontext because it is placed by my datatemplate. So in blend, when I open my view to edit its design, I have no datas to bind to my view. If I set a datacontext to my detailview, in blend I can see all datas I can bind but in runtime, the datacontext set by datatemplate is overrided by the datacontext set in my detailview, so I have no datas during runtime.

Does anyone knows how I can create a good MVVM project, with views managed by datatemplates and with datacontext that we can see with Blend ?

Thanks,

Comment: Hi Steeve. Do you have any code to share?

Comment: Other questions, Why does your viewmodel bind to a view?  It should be the opposite, viewmodels bind to Views.

Comment: Hi Ray,
In fact, I'm using the same principle that you can see here : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/InternationalizedWizard.aspx
You have a master viewmodel that have a currentView property (as object).You have two detail viewmodels (let's name theim VMdetail1 and VMdetail2).In my master view,

Comment: I have a contentControler whose source is binded to MasterViewModel.CurrentView property.
In my xaml resources I have datatemplates like this :
 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DetailViewModel1}">
        <local:DetailView1 />
    </DataTemplate>
And in my views I have no datacontext

Comment: DetailViews datacontexts are set by datatemplate at runtime.
When you change the currentview to viewmodel1, it loads the corresponding view with datatemplate.
My problem is with blend you can't see datas to bind in your detailview because there is no datacontext. If I add a datacontext in my

Comment: detailview, the one loaded by my masterviewmodel is overrided by the one declared in my view. If my explanation is not clear, you will find more details in the article I've posted before, under this title : Doesn't work with Developper/Designer process (VS2008 / Blend)
Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

I've got a blog post on this issue: http://www.robfe.com/2009/08/design-time-data-in-expression-blend-3/

My post is all about showing data in blend *without* having to have that data displayed or even created at runtime.

Comment: Your post is really good. It's the best solution for that problem. It took 10 hours for me until I found the "fake" datacontext.

Comment: Thanks! When you say it took 10 hours, do you think I could improve the post a little?

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar issue in this post:
[How can I use Expression Blend to edit a DataTemplate created in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824539/how-can-i-use-expression-blend-to-edit-a-datatemplate-created-in-visual-studio)